# How can I match/identify articles (An,A,The) in a string to move to the end of a string

Tags: php, regex

For sorting purposes, I'd like to ignore the articles in the titles being sorted.  I've been able to do it in MySQL, but I need to duplicate in PHP.

Titles:

```
A Tale of Two Cities      --> Tale of Two Cities, A
An Unexpected Journey     --> Unexpected Journey, An
The Lord Of the Rings     --> Lord Of The Rings, The

$sortable = preg_replace([A |An |The]...
```

I've got a bit of a convoluted array processing routine that I'd like to replace with a simple preg_xxx statement if possible.  Have tinkered enough, and trust me, "what have I tried" would only confuse the question, lol.

For future reference, here's the same thing in pure MySQL:

```
SELECT Title,
    CASE WHEN SUBSTRING_INDEX(Title, ' ', 1) IN ('a', 'an', 'the')
        THEN CONCAT(
            SUBSTRING(Title, INSTR(Title, ' ') + 1),
            ', ',
            SUBSTRING_INDEX(Title, ' ', 1)
        )
        ELSE Title
    END AS Sortable
FROM Titles
ORDER BY Sortable
```

Comment: What if there are more than 1 `A` or `An`'s present on a single sentence?

Comment: you want to shift only articles in the 1st position of strings?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Capture from the beginning of the string and replace with the back-references in reverse:

```
$sortable = preg_replace('/^(A|An|The) (.+)/', '$2, $1', $title);
```

### Summary:

- `^` matches the beginning of the string
- followed by **A** OR **An** OR **The** followed by a space
- followed by any character `.` 1 or more times `+`
- parentheses `()` are a capture group and capture what was matched and are referenced in the replace by `$1` for the first group and `$2` for the second

Comment: This is perfect, I'm certain of it because its like reading Klingon to me..Thanks!!

Comment: Sorry, added an explanation.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you could check the string against an array of articles, explode it, and then move the article to the end:

```
$articles = ['A', 'An', 'The'];

$titles = [
    'A Tale of Two Cities',
    'An Unexpected Journey',
    'The Lord of the Rings',
];

foreach ($titles as $title) {
    if (preg_match('/^('.implode('|', $articles).')\s/', $title, $matches)) {
        $title = preg_replace('/^'.$matches[1].'\s/', '', $title).', '.$matches[0];
    }
}
```

Comment: @AbraCadaver’s answer is much cleaner! As you can see: regular expressions aren’t my strong suit!